# How should we fix UIFields in all iphone inches using Auto-layouts?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am developing one project using Auto-layouts.

But I am facing here one problem in Register page i.e

In 4 inch screen all UIFields fit perfectly, but in 6 inch screen there is some "space" coming at "bottom" side as like below 6 inch screen.

How should I resolve this problem?

And I am posting screen which Auto-layouts I have applied.

### Applied Constraints:

[image]

### 4 inch:

[image]

### 6 inch:

[image]

Main problem is coming here 6 inch screen some space is coming at bottom side it's not seems like Good how should I resolve this problem?

Comment: @Elydasian, thank you, but according to Meta Stack Overflow recommendations, you should not search one specific user's posts to edit, so I'd advice to avoid more edits on Krish posts. Also, when suggesting edits, please remove the fluff ("_I'm new at..."_, _"please help"_, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that all those button should always remain with same distance from bottom line then you can add constraint from main view's bottom (bottom space to bottom layout guide) for Register button instead of related to password field for Login button.
Then add vertical spacing to the Forgot Password button related to Register button, and vertical spacing for Login button related to Forgot Password button. Like Below :

[image]

For Register Button , Add constraints :

[image]

For Forget Password Button, Add constraints : 
[image]

And for Login Button, add constraints : 
[image]

Comment: where did you give top space for login Button?

Comment: this is not acceeptable solution

Comment: you can have all constraints from bottom instead of top.